# Arduino/Genuino 101 5 volts pin

Tags: pins, voltage-level, 101

Still trying to understand the nomenclature of the pins, I am confused of what's the function of the +5V pin, as I read that the 101 should not operate at that tension.

What's it for?

Comment: That is just a regulated 5V and it is 5 tolerant.

Comment: What does a regulated input means? And why can I use it without damaging the pins?

Comment: Regulated input refers to regulated power input. And The board operating voltage and I/O is 3.3V but all pins are protected against 5V overvoltage So, that doesn't means you will want to power the board with 5V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Genuino 5V pin is a DC regulated pin. That means when you supply Power (9 to 12 V) to Vin or through the DC Jack, a 5V voltage regulator regulates to give constant output at 5 V. The purpose of that pin is to provide 5V output for other use- as a power supply to some sensor you are interfacing or anything.

However, you can power up the Genuino 101 via the 5V pin. But that is not advisable because in that case it will bypass the regulator present in the board and can damage the circuit if improperly regulated.

Comment: fwiw, i've never seen an unregulated 5v psu output...

Comment: yes, otherwise how could you get a constant voltage.

Comment: Oh, my misconception was that because of the sign of the voltage (positive) I was assuming it to be an input pin, in the sense voltage would go to, and not from, there. Thanks for the help